# Any way to run PLSQL Procedures locally through TOAD?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, toad

At my company, only DBAs have permissions to create Views, stored procedures, functions, ect. Currently today, whenever I want to run complex functions or queries, I have to write everything within a single script. This makes my scripts large and repetitive, as many of my scripts perform similar functions.

Is there any way to save and run a procedure, function or view locally or in a personal location, and not store it on the Oracle database? This script

```
create or replace procedure <userSchema>.MyTest AS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('This is a test');
End;
```

gives the error

```
[Error] Compilation (1: 1): ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It really what it says - You don't have sufficient privileges to create the procedure.

Comment: I understand that... I am asking if there is another way to perform the same functionality.

Comment: Well, no.  The way to store db procedure code is to use the stored-procedures feature.  If your DBAs won't let you do that, they're crippling your ability to do meaningful software development in the database.

Comment: Agree with Dave Costa, sounds like the DBAs have convinced management that only they have the special knowledge required to write a procedure and not "destroy" the database.  In most environments, you'd have a sensible way to promote code (including stored procedures) from dev through production.  This would typically be written by developers, not DBAs.  Anyway, what you're looking for is a work-around, but you have bigger issues in this environment I think...

Comment: Ok thanks, I appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up a directory with multiple files - one per anonymous block of code. these will effectively be your 'procedures'. A SQLPlus script can call each 'procedure' using @the_procedure.sql feature as required while passing whatever parameters are needed.

If you make the directory location shared on a network then anyone with SQLPlus will be able to run any of your 'procedures' in the same way.

How workable this is for you will largely depend on what sort of interaction between the various procedures you are expecting.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how this would work, or provide a link to a guide? I'm not sure what functionality you are referring to.

Comment: The '@' simply runs the SQL script. Script file will contain the anonymous block. Where it may get complicated is moving results from one 'procedure' to the next or calling a 'procedure' from within another.

Comment: @BenJ - I suspect that a combination of suggestions here may well be required. When you are happy that something answers your question consider marking it as such and consider up-voting others that you find useful.

Comment: I upvoted comments, but because I have less than 15 score they are invisible upvotes. I marked your answer as correct, as its the closest I can get to what I am looking for. It takes some questionable logic to make it work, but ultimately it works, and that's what I am looking for.

Thanks again!

Comment: @BenJ - You don't need to mark as answered if it doesn't really do the job. Also, it may look a convoluted way to do things but the correct way would be to have packages/functions/procedures. There are ways that can control who is running what - I would petition your manager and the DBAs to be allowed some leeway with creating objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can declare the procedure in an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2       PROCEDURE MyTest AS
  3       BEGIN
  4            dbms_output.put_line('This is a test');
  5       END;
  6  BEGIN
  7       MyTest();
  8  END;
  9  /
This is a test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: This is nearly what I am doing today - while it works, it's repetitive when I am performing similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

Store your code as anonymous block in Toad as Named SQL.

- To save it **Editor | Add to Named SQLs**.
- To get it **CTRL+N** or   **View | SQL Command Recall | Named**.

P.S. Code will be accesible only on your PC with installed Toad.

Comment: This might be exactly what I am looking for. Doing some investigation now.

Comment: Ah darn, this doesn't quite do what I need. I want to be able to call the function directly without having to actually insert the functions code into my script. Thanks though!

Comment: No you will not be able to do it directly. But it will help you help to easier manage your scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can define a (temporary) procedure (or function) inside an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
declare
  var1 integer;
  var2 varchar(100);

  procedure print(p_what varchar)
  as
  begin
     dbms_output.put_line(p_what);
  end;

begin
  print('Doing stuff');
  insert into some_value (id) values (42);
  delete from other_table;
  print('Deleted '||SQL%ROWCOUNT||' rows');

  update foobar 
     set answer = 42;
  print('Updated '||SQL%ROWCOUNT||' rows');
end;
/
```

But that has the limitation that the procedure is only visible in **that** block, not outside of it.